# Placing gaussian function at different points on mesh

Tags: matlab, random, gaussian

I am looking to create a random distribution of gaussian curve shapes on a large mesh. I basically want to take this function :

```
Z = 0.3*exp(-5*(x.^2+y.^2))-0.1;
Z(Z<0)=0;
```

and be able to choose its location (in x & y coords), and have multiple plots.

So at the moment, I have this:

[image: Single Point]

But I would like to have this generated:

[image: Distributed]

Is there a reasonably simple way to do this? I have tried to play around with the code but I am afraid I'm not a mathematics, nor a MATLAB expert.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just add all the `Z` matrices you're plotting together, generating a single matrix with all 10 baubles. Plot that one the same way as you generated the first one.

Comment: With random generation, it's entirely possible that the Gaussians may overlap.  Is this allowed?

Comment: At this stage, i would like to keep them separate, I was thinking of just discounting any random numbers that would cause an overlap

Comment: What's your criterion for overlap?

Comment: Maybe you've already realised this, but one issue is `Z = 0.3*exp(-5*(x.^2+y.^2))-0.1;` is centered at the origin `(0,0)`. You need to generate functions that are centered at given `(xm, ym)` coordinates, your random points. This is achieved by a function `Z = 0.3*exp(-5*((x-xm).^2+(y-ym).^2))-0.1;`. Even this is not the most general form for a bivariate Gaussian function, see e.g [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariateNormalDistribution.html).

Comment: If you can put it on one point you can surely also put it on many (different) points. Just keep on adding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at this!

the way this works:

1. Generate random point
2. Check if point is closer than sigma
3. If its not, then create a gaussian there!
4. repeat until Ngaussians reached

code:

```
clear
n_gaussians=15;
gaussians=0;
sigma=1; % std
mindist=sigma; % if distance is smaller than this gaussians "collide"

[x,y]= meshgrid(-5:0.1:5,-5:0.1:5);
used=[];
Z=zeros(size(x));
while gaussians<n_gaussians

    xm=(rand(1)-0.5)*10;
    ym=(rand(1)-0.5)*10;
    notvalid=0;
    for ii=1:size(used,2)
        % if we are too close to any point.
       if norm([xm-used(1,ii),ym-used(2,ii)])<mindist
           notvalid=1; % do not add this gauusian
       end
    end
    if notvalid
        continue
    end
    used(:,end+1)=[xm;ym];
    Zaux = 0.3/sigma*exp(-5*((x-xm).^2+(y-ym).^2)/sigma.^2)-0.1;
    Zaux(Zaux<0)=0;
    Z=Z+Zaux;
    gaussians=gaussians+1;
end

surf(x,y,Z);
axis equal
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Exactly what I was after

Comment: After running a few times I do still seem to be getting overlap. I have played about with the coeff of sigma but it's still creating points together. Do you know why this could be happening?

Comment: @andy-m You are rigth, the code had bugs (now fixed). Now it should work, but, in a domain as small as this one, 3*sigma turns to be a too big distance. I reduced it.